# AutoResizeLimit for Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

How can I set AutoResizeLimit when creating a Cloud SQL MySQL instance? 
The GCP API defines it here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances
The terraform provider has disk_autoresize, which is a boolean:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html#disk_autoresize

But, there is no attribute to set the auto_resize_limit.

Answer (score 0):

A way to [create a Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance) with auto_resize_limit is to create it directly with querying an API e.g. with `cURL` and setting [`storageAutoResizeLimit`](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances#settings.storageAutoResizeLimit).

The query should look like this:

```
ACCESS_TOKEN="$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"
curl --header "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
     --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     --data '{"name":"[INSTANCE_NAME]", "region":"[REGION]",
              "settings": {"tier":"[MACHINE_TYPE]",
              "storageAutoResizeLimit":[SIZE],
              "backupConfiguration": {"binaryLogEnabled":true, "enabled":true}}}' \
     -X POST \
     https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/[PROJECT-ID]/instances
```

Note that `storageAutoResize` is set to `True` by default.